# Amazon serverless image handler, CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've got an amazon serverless Image Handler Deployed, as per documentation from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/deployment.html

which works perfectly well & I get images with dimension changes.

Now when I am using those images in canvas or webGL based code  `"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"`

Then I referred below this

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/

And configured my CloudFront behavior accordingly.
Still, I am getting the same issue. What is it which I am missing
Below is my CloudFront Behavior tab configuration.
[image: My]

And Below is my S3 CORS configuration

[image]

Still I am getting same issue. What is it which I am missing

Comment: What HTTP method are you using to do HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

S3 adds CORS headers only if Origin header is added to the request.
From your problem, you can try below:
1. Invalidate the cache once to verify the Origin header whitelisting took place by accessing the link again and check if it's a MISS from CloudFront. (In this case it can be error from CloudFront because of Lambda@edge Origin response error handling)
2. check the request made by lambda logs in CloudWatch and logs the request to see if it sends Origin header to S3.